# Learning: Should I learn TDD before learning Design Patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, tdd

I found a topic online that says that TDD is a foundation to learning design patterns because it forces you to think a lot about your code.

One persons opinion to learning design patterns:

- Learn TDD
- Learn refactoring
- Learn patterns

Should I learn TDD before design patterns or do both in parallel?

Answer (score 4):

You can/should do both in **parallel**.
Read some articles about Design Patterns, and some articles/books about TDD.

The goal of TDD is to help designing the code, not testing code. 
Testing is just a side effect of TDD.

To fully benefit of the refactoring cycle of TDD, design patterns may be emerged.
So a knowledge of design patterns is clearly useful.

Answer (score 1):

More than a theory **TDD** is a paradigm/practice. Simply you should write your tests (unit tests) before you write your code.

The main concern behind that opinion is when you practice TDD you are automatically forced to

- Determine your ***units***(For what you are writing your tests) first, before you write your actual code.
- Make your ***units much simpler***, in order to make it testable.

Ultimately those are two main goals of applying **Design Patterns**, i.e. what are the units?, how to make them simpler? So automatically you are prompted to apply design patterns before you write your code (when you write unit tests first).

Personally I agree that you can take both parallel. Indeed TDD is just a practice. By practice, you can improve. Design patterns are something relatively theoretical. You can definitely try applying them when you are practicing TDD. :))